# Is there any way to create self signed certificate for " *.cloudapp.net " azure website

Tags: azure, ssl

I have a cloud service on Azure with URL like {mysubdomain}.cloudapp.net

I am creating self signed certificate from my local system and deployed on Azure

But certificate is not authorizing as it is not matching domain correctly.

Is there any way we can create self sign certificate for *.cloudapp.net?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not planning on using a custom domain name, but are instead planning on using the *.azurewebsites.net domain assigned to your web app by Azure (for example, contoso.azurewebsites.net) then HTTPS is already enabled on your site with a certificate from Microsoft. You can use https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net to access your App. However, *.azurewebsites.net is a wildcard domain. Like all wildcard domains, it is not as secure as using a custom domain with your own certificate.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/